# selenium-webdriver wont work with dual proxy

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried the following snippet to open a browser with a dual proxy but it did not work, also single proxy is working.

Is there any way to find out dual proxy setting/configuration ?

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    //profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "firstproxy");
    //profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", port_firstproxy);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "secondproxy");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", port_secondproxy);
    profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-us, en");
    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
    driver.get("url");
```

Comment: Can you post you error log also.

Comment: No error is producing explicitly, But yes, desired output is not coming. Like url should open. But now, only browser is opening in new window with no url.